# Java - String comparing among many txt files

Tags: java

I have a simple program that:

- Parse txt files in java
- transforms data in unix timestamp
- Keeps only one line of values for each second

Below there's the code.
The txt files are in this format:

> 21/03/2013    04:18:23    6890    6830    6850    6770    6830    6400    6630    6710    6770    6850    35024   34976
>   21/03/2013  04:18:23    6910    6800    6850    6770    6820    6410    6590    6710    6780    6820    35056   34976
>   21/03/2013  04:18:24    6890    6820    6860    6770    6830    6400    6580    6720    6770    6830    34912   34880
>   21/03/2013  04:18:24    6860    6840    6840    6770    6830    6390    6660    6700    6740    6890    35008   34880

My program transforms the code in this way:

> put sensor.rat.128 1364278801 7100 sensor=A
>
> put sensor.rat.128 1364278801 6910 sensor=B
>
> put sensor.rat.128 1364278801 6890 sensor=C
>
> put sensor.rat.128 1364278801 6630 sensor=D

The program works very well with on txt file, in the sense that it keeps only one lines of values for each second, but if there is a same second value in different txt files, it can't be able to recognize them.

**So the question is:** how can i make the code save only one list of values for each second and across multiples files?
I hope all of you understand.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class Downsampler {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        /*
        * Scans all the files in a specified folder
        * Obtains Cell number from the file name
        */
        String path = "/home/alessandro/Data128prova"; // name of path
        File folder = new File(path);

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (s.hasNext()){
                    list.add(s.next());
                }
            s.close();

            //Arraylist to save modified values
            ArrayList<String> ds = new ArrayList<String>();

           int i;
            String app = "";
                for(i=0; i<=list.size()-13; i=i+14){

        //combining the first to values to obtain data  
        String str = list.get(i)+" "+list.get(i+1);

        //------convert data in epoch time
            Date dt= new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(str);
            long epochlong = dt.getTime()/1000;
            String epoch = Long.toString(epochlong);
        //------end conversion data 

                    if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase(app)){
                    //add all the other values to arraylist ds
                    ds.add(epoch);
                    int j;
            for(j=1; j<14; j++){
            ds.add(list.get(i+j));
                        }
                    }
        app = str;
                }

    int k;
        String metric = "sensor.rat.128.riprova"; //name of the metric
    for (k=0; k<=ds.size()-13; k=k+14){
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+2)+" sensor=A");
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+3)+" sensor=B");   
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+4)+" sensor=C");   
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+5)+" sensor=D");
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+6)+" sensor=E");   
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+7)+" sensor=F");   
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+8)+" sensor=G");   
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+9)+" sensor=H");
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+10)+" sensor=I");  
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+11)+" sensor=L");  
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+12)+" sensor=M");  
    System.out.println ("put "+metric+" "+ds.get(k)+" "+ds.get(k+13)+" sensor=N");
    }


    } //end of for  
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the question mark?

Comment: Is your data written to the file file chronologically so that earlier values in a file are never written after later values in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Map and the time as a key to store your dataset.  The next time you see that time point across any of the files you are parsing, you can decide how you want to treat the new dataset (drop it, average it with the current dataset for that time, etc.).  Here's your code updated to use a Map to associate the dataset with a specific time.  This code just prints a statement to indicate it's already processed a specific time.  You should insert your own code to do something with duplicates.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Downsampler
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

        /*
        * Scans all the files in a specified folder
        * Obtains Cell number from the file name
        */
      String path = "/tmp/data"; // name of path
      File folder = new File(path);

      Map<Long, List<String>> timeValuesMap = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();
      for (File file : folder.listFiles())
      {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
         ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
         while (s.hasNext())
         {
            list.add(s.next());
         }
         s.close();

         //Arraylist to save modified values
         ArrayList<String> ds = new ArrayList<String>();

         int i;
         String app = "";
         for (i = 0; i <= list.size() - 13; i = i + 14)
         {

            //combining the first to values to obtain data
            String str = list.get(i) + " " + list.get(i + 1);

            //------convert data in epoch time
            Date dt = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(str);
            long epochlong = dt.getTime() / 1000;
            String epoch = Long.toString(epochlong);
            //------end conversion data

            if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase(app))
            {
               //add all the other values to arraylist ds
               ds.add(epoch);
               int j;
               for (j = 1; j < 14; j++)
               {
                  ds.add(list.get(i + j));
               }
            }
            app = str;

            if(timeValuesMap.containsKey(epochlong))
            {
               System.out.println("Already processed time: " +  str);
               //do something - ignore values, average across sensor, min/max, etc...
               //newds = doSomeOperation(ds);
               //timeValuesMap.put(epochlong, newds);
            }
            else
            {

               System.out.println("New time: " +  str);
               timeValuesMap.put(epochlong, ds);
            }
         }

         int k;
         String metric = "sensor.rat.128.riprova"; //name of the metric
         for (k = 0; k <= ds.size() - 13; k = k + 14)
         {
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 2) + " sensor=A");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 3) + " sensor=B");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 4) + " sensor=C");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 5) + " sensor=D");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 6) + " sensor=E");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 7) + " sensor=F");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 8) + " sensor=G");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 9) + " sensor=H");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 10) + " sensor=I");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 11) + " sensor=L");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 12) + " sensor=M");
            System.out.println("put " + metric + " " + ds.get(k) + " " + ds.get(k + 13) + " sensor=N");
         }

      } //end of for
   }
}
```

**NOTE:**  for very large datasets, this may cause the JVM to run out of memory as the number of items in the Map becomes very large.

Comment: Unfortunately i've about 1GB of data (and it's only a part of it). I'm afraid that this solution as you said, will get JVM run out of memory

Comment: Maybe so.  It depends on how much RAM you can provide to the JVM, and how many unique timestamps you have in your data.   Of course each unique timestamp would be an entry in the Map, but if you have many duplicates your Map might not be too big.